# Expected time to walk in Manhattan

Tags: probability, combinatorics, integer-lattices

Suppose you are at coordinate $(m,n)$, and wish to go to $(0,0)$ using unit steps, either down or left. However, at each point, there is a traffic light, which switches from allowing horizontal to vertical crossing every 10 seconds. All crossings are independent, you you can assume that when you reach a crossing, there is a uniform distribution of which state it is in when you reach it.

As long as we are at $(m,n)$ with $m,n\geq 1$, we can choose if we wish to go vertically or horizontally, so we of course cross the street in the direction which is green.
The tricky part is what happens after one of the coordinates become $0$.

Since the [Manhattan distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taxicab_geometry) from $(0,0)$ to $(m,n)$ is constant for every path, we don't really need to consider walking speed.

**So, what is the expected total waiting time?**

EDIT: So, the expected time to go from $(1,0)$ to $(0,0)$ would be $10/4$ seconds, since with 50% probability, there is no need to wait at all, and in the other case, the average waiting time is $5$ seconds.

Thus, the expected time from $(k,0)$ to $(0,0)$ is $10k/4$.

Define
$$
f(m,n) = \sum_{k=0}^m \frac{10k}{4}\frac{\text{number of paths from (m,n) to (k,0)}}{\text{total number of paths leading to an edge}}
$$
Hence, expected time from $(m,n)$ to $(0,0)$ is then $f(m,n)+f(n,m)$.

Comment: This is just a question I was thinking about when walking home. It is not homework. I have not worked out the details, but I find it quite beautiful, so I want to share it.

Comment: When you was thinking you haven´t made any thoughts about the solution ?

Comment: I understand the problem as you state it; your post suggest that your crossing choices are greedy, in that you take whichever crossing is available.  It seems like if we add choice then the expected waiting time will decrease.  For instance, suppose when you arrive at $(2,1)$, you can walk down, or wait $.00001$ seconds for the light to change.  You're better off waiting out that minuscule amount of time.

Comment: @PerAlexandersson for those of us who are unfamiliar with the geographical layout of Manhatten (though I am aware that is is mostly formed of grids - hence lattice connotations), do you wish to estimate a realistic time (if so, please provide references - you might look [here, for example](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/100920/zooming-using-geographics), or do you want an ideal representation to take the place of the desired location (again,please provide refs.)?

Comment: @MarcusM: That's an interesting variation, but then one needs to define how long time it takes to walk a block. 
Also, in my city, it is not obvious to see how long waiting time there is until it becomes green.

Comment: By the way, in Manhattan, the blocks aren't square. It takes longer going one way than another. This suggests a variation on your problem. (Also, Broadway goes down at a weird angle. But this seems less relevant.)

Comment: @AkivaWeinberger: Manhattan distance is a precise mathematical notion, also known as taxicab geometry. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taxicab_geometry

Comment: Yes, I know.${}$

Comment: So it takes no time to move from one point to another, assuming the light allows for movement in the direction you want to travel? And by minutes do you mean seconds?

Comment: @cheesyfluff Well, you need to walk exactly m+k blocks, independent of which path you take, so you can add $(m+k)\times walkingSpeed$ to your final expected time if that feels closer to reality, but it does not change the core of the problem by including/neglecting this walking time.

Comment: $$\sum_{i=0}^{m-1}(\frac 1 2)^{n+i}\binom {n-1+i}i(m-i)+\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}(\frac 1 2)^{m+i}\binom {m-1+i}i(n-i)$$
if time between light switches is $4$. The distributions inside the sum are negative binomials times $(m-i)$ which gives use one of the terms ($m$) in terms of regularized incomplete beta.

Comment: Rough estimates: if $n\ll m$, then expected time to hit the edge is $\approx 2n$, hence average number of block on the edges is $EB=m+n-2n=m-n$ and average time waiting (per block walked) is $\alpha=1-\frac {2n}{n+m}$. If $m=n\gg 1$, $EB\approx \sqrt{2n}$ and $\alpha=\frac 1{\sqrt{2n}}$.